# Regular expressions in Notepad++: replace with first character of part of the regex

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

In notepad++, I'm able to use the following regex to find instances of a string that I want to replace:

```
(<span class=")(.*?)(" title=")(.*?)(">)(.*?)(</span>)
```

I know that I could use '\2' or '\4' to replace the found text with the string in the second or fourth set of parantheses respectively. But what I'd like to do is replace the found text with the first character of the string in the second set of parantheses, combined with the first character of the string in the fourth set of parantheses.

Any idea how to do this? Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Please provide an example of the input and desired output.

Comment: <span class="heart" title="8 of Hearts">8</span> replaced by 8h; <span class="club" title="T of Clubs">10</span> replaced by Tc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex pattern to use is

`(<span class=")(.)(.*?)(" title=")(.)(.*?)(">)(.*?)(</span>)`

and the replacement:

`\5\2`

we need to add more capturing groups in order to replace the string appropriately.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use capture groups when not mandatory:

Find what: `<span class="(.).*?" title="(.).*?">.*?</span>`
Replace with: `$2$1`